# Sencha Keyboard in PhoneGap causes gap when hidden

Tags: iphone, cordova, extjs

Recently my Phonegap + Sencha app has been causing some problems by leaving a blank space at the bottom of the screen when I hide a keyboard. This can end up being a large space if I scrolled through multiple fields before hiding the keyboard. Help please!?

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using? Are you seeing this happen specifically on Android?

Comment: its cordova 2.3.0 but it also does it in 2.2.0. This happens on both platforms, but I work mostly with iOS and that is where I've been seeing it the most. I would post pictures but my reputation isn't high enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out my issue was different from probably anybody else's, but if this applies to you I hope it helps.

The problem is that I was using a splash image for my loading indicator. This is located in the index.html and was a placeholder while the sencha app was loading. I had the splash image extending below the screen 20 or so pixels and when the keyboard would hide, the main panel for the sencha app would reset to 20px above the bottom of the screen.

Solution: If you use a splash image for the loading indicator, make it bottom:0px.